# Query with elastic4s yielding zero results

Tags: python, scala, elasticsearch, elastic4s

I'm playing with and learning scala and elastic4s for elasticsearch.

I have a python script that uses the official elasticsearch module. My code in python looks like this:

```
res=helpers.scan(es, query={"_source": ["http_uri", "header_user_agent"],"query": {"query_string": {"query": "message:key"}}}, index="")
```

My above python code works. I get 900k results and I process them and so on.

I'm using the basic scala code to try out e4s. This is just a simple query. Is my query wrong?

```
import com.sksamuel.elastic4s.ElasticClient
import com.sksamuel.elastic4s.ElasticDsl._

object Banana {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        val client = ElasticClient.local

        val res = client execute { search in "*"  query "apiKey" } await

        println(res.getHits.totalHits)

        println(res)
    }
}
```

My result on running this:

```
info] Running Banana
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
0
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 0,
    "successful" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 0,
    "max_score" : 0.0,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
```

And the response with a curl query:

```
$ curl -s 'localhost:9200/_search?q=apiKey&pretty=true' | head -12
{
  "took" : 21,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1200,
    "successful" : 1200,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 756253,
    "max_score" : 1.5905869,
    "hits" : [ {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val client = ElasticClient.local
```

this line means that `elastic4s` will create it's own data store, so if you not index your data into this place, your search result is nothing. if you want to connect your own `Elasticsearch`, you can:

```
  //Set the Cluster name
  val settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder().put("cluster.name", "elasticsearch").build()

  //Set the Cluster Connection
  val client = ElasticClient.remote(settings, ("127.0.0.1", 9300))
```

and do the search action.

Comment: That method is deprecated. So, I used 
`val uri = ElasticsearchClientUri("elasticsearch://127.0.0.1:9300")`
`val client = ElasticClient.remote(uri)`


Nope. no work.


`[error] (run-main-0) org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available: []`
`org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available: []`

Comment: Maybe you can check https://github.com/sksamuel/elastic4s/blob/master/guide/search.md to search.

Answer (score 3):

@chengpohi is correct that you are creating a local node and not connecting to your cluster when you use `val client = ElasticClient.local`, so you need to use

```
val uri = ElasticsearchClientUri("elasticsearch://127.0.0.1:9300") 
val settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder().put("cluster.name", "myClusterName").build()
val client = ElasticClient.remote(settings, uri)
```

But in addition you are searching in an index called `*` which does not mean all indexes as you think it does. If you want to search in all indexes, then you need to use `_all` eg

```
client execute { 
  search in "_all" query "findme" 
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Had to add this to make it work: 
`val uri = ElasticsearchClientUri("elasticsearch://127.0.0.1:9300")` 
`val settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder().put("cluster.name", "myClusterName").build()` 
`val client = ElasticClient.remote(settings,(uri))`

Comment: Additionally, this also worked.
`val resp = client.execute { search in "*" query "bananas" }.await`

Comment: I've updated the answer to include the cluster name.

Comment: also thank you for elastic4s. love it over the other scala elasticsearch clients. 

Comment: @monkjack I am running into the same problem but I have set my client to same settings you have recommended. You can view it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30602459/getting-zero-results-in-search-using-elastic4s).